How to design a cascading selection process in filters
I'm designing a filter for a tickets table in a SaaS product. This filter has a cascading selection process. There are two categories: A and B. Category B is dependent on the selection made in Category A. Essentially, choosing an item from Category A dynamically populates Category B with relevant options. Users can then select an item from the filtered Category B to refine their ticket search. How to design this in a way that is user friendly and not something out of the blue.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

To add to @Lonut's answer (and use their example), be sure to account for deselection too. What happens if the user selects Audi instead of BMW? This should reset the Model dropdown.

Implement Category A as a dropdown list.
As soon as a selection is made in Category A, trigger the loading of Category B options.
Load Category B options based on the selection from Category A.
Example below, you need to select first the car manufacturer and after you can select the model because model is dependent on manufacturer.


Hey, very smart answer. It solves all the use cases except one tiny one, we have to make this product for even the smallest use cases as well. Now, if the user wants to select multiple selections in Categories A and B... with dropdown, that isn't possible, maybe with chips... but I have to keep in mind that Category A has 20 items, and Category B across all selections has 100s of items... so maybe chips with a search bar make more sense... but yeah, it ruins the experience a little bit. I apologise for not clarifying this in my question. I will update my question soon.

For example, you showed that you can use an empty state for the second dropdown list, where you'll show a hint for users. I have experience working on similar products. Users who use such products usually know that, at first, they need to select the make/manufacture of a vehicle.

You can use progressive disclosure while providing solution for this. By that what I mean is, First allow user to select/multi-select Category A, then based on that selection, show category B dropdown. I believe if you observe Google Ads filters, they're done in same way. See if this fits in your use case.
Attaching a screenshot for your reference.

